# How could I iterate over images with pattern name in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to iterate over a folder with images given by Kitti dataset. The pattern is '0000000001.png' ... to '0000001169.png' for example, but the number of images may be different for a folder. How could I achieve this in c++?

I need to change by myself the image name, since there are other processings involved

Comment: I know there are ways to do it using `std::filesystem` but I don't know the solution yet

Comment: There should be some examples in your C++ textbook that you can use as a pattern. Is there something on this topic in your textbook that's unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with a code similar to this sample code:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <regex>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    const auto search_path = ".";
    const std::regex base_regex(".*\\.png");
    std::smatch base_match;

    for(auto it = fs::directory_iterator(search_path); it != fs::directory_iterator(); ++it) {
        if(it->is_regular_file() && std::regex_match(it->path().filename().native(), base_match, base_regex)) {
            std::cout << *it;
        }
    }
}
```